# How to get children element that contains self closing tag in beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

I have two input element(which is self closing tag) in each div but I am only getting one input element.

Here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4.element import Tag

html_doc = '''<cfform>

<div name="first_div">
  First name:<cfinput type="text" name="firstname">
  Last name:<cfinput type="text" name="lastname">
</div>
<div name="second_div">
  Address:<cfinput type="text" name="address">
  Contact Number:<cfinput type="text" name="contact_number">
</div>

</cfform>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'xml')
for div in soup.find_all("div"):
    print(div.get("name"))
    for child in div.children:
        if isinstance(child, Tag):
            print(" ", child.get("name"))
```

Comment: `cfinput` isn't an HTML tag, and it doesn't end with `/>`.  How is BS to know the tag is self-closing?  Is the second `cfinput` tag being parsed as a child of the first one?

Answer (score 0):

[CCO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6791802/cco) is exactly right. If you modify your `<cfinput>` tags to indicate that they are self-closing, by adding a `/` like `<cfinput/>`, you'll get the output we want to see.

**Your code with CCO's suggestion**:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4.element import Tag

html_doc = '''<cfform>

<div name="first_div">
  First name:<cfinput type="text" name="firstname"/>
  Last name:<cfinput type="text" name="lastname"/>
</div>
<div name="second_div">
  Address:<cfinput type="text" name="address"/>
  Contact Number:<cfinput type="text" name="contact_number"/>
</div>

</cfform>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'xml')
for div in soup.find_all("div"):
    print(div.get("name"))
    for child in div.children:
        if isinstance(child, Tag):
            print(" ", child.get("name"))
```

**Output after I ran the above**:

> first_div
>   (' ', u'firstname')
>   (' ', u'lastname')
>   second_div
>   (' ', u'address')
>   (' ', u'contact_number')